# How do I display the value of a row?

Tags: php, mysql, class, object, mysqli

**I have five rows setup in a MySQLi database:**

```
$title, $subtitle, $owner, $contactemail, and $footer.
```

Instead of writing out my websites title on EVERY .php page, I would like to use a function that will **display the value of $title, $subtitle**, etc.

This is what I have done so far:

**index.php**

```
<?php include 'config.php'; ?>
<?echo $title;?>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = 'localhost';
$mysql_username = 'root';
$mysql_dbname = 'toplist';
$mysql_password = '';

$dbh= new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

$query = "SELECT * FROM toplist_settings";

$title=['title'];
$subtitle=['subtitle'];
$owner=['owner'];
$contactemail=['contactemail'];
$footer=['footer'];
?>
```

But this is not working. When I use , etc. nothing shows up.

Comment: `$footer=['footer'];` - what is this?

Comment: You should follow http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php

Comment: The `$query` is never executed, and the last variables (`$title`, `$subtitle`, etc.) are all arrays with one value in them. You obviously have no idea what you are doing, so you should go read a tutorial that [covers the basics of PHP](http://php.net/tutorial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
   $query = "SELECT * FROM toplist_settings";
   $stmt = $dbh->query($query); 
   $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $title=$row['title'];
    $subtitle=$row['subtitle'];
    $owner=$row['owner'];
    $contactemail=$row['contactemail'];
    $footer=$row['footer'];
```

Comment: It's also possible that the `toplist_settings` table has columns `setting_name` and `setting_value`, and each of these settings is a separate row. The OP *did* say "five rows" in the question.

Answer (score 0):

execute your query to get records

```
  $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM toplist_settings");  
  print_r( $query->execute());
```